# php replacement and interesction of 2 nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say we have a nested array1:

```
 $array1=
 [function_maps =>
      [subid=>1,
       transaction=>2
      ]
 ]
```

and array2 looks something like this:

```
 $array2=
 [function_maps =>
      [subid=>4,
       purchace=40EUR
      ]
 ]
```

So I want to have a resulting array like this:

```
$array3=
 [function_maps =>
      [subid=>4,
       transaction=>2,
       purchace=40EUR
      ]
 ]
```

So as you see, the values existing from array1 and array2, we prefer array2 values. And where there is not intersection, both values are taken into the new array.

How can I reach this? knowing the array can go deep (nested array, maybe up to 3 levels).

**Edit with solution:**

People from IRC chat gave me the solution, which easily solves the case:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive solution. Try the following function:

```
function replace_recursive(array &$array1, &$array2 = null) {
    $merged = $array1;

    if (is_array($array2)) {
        foreach ($array2 as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($array2[$key])) {
                if (is_array($merged[$key])) {
                  $merged[$key] = replace_recursive($merged[$key], $array2[$key]);
                } else {
                  $merged[$key] = $array2[$key];
                }
            } else {
                $merged[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Example:

```
$array1 = ['function_maps' => ['subid' => 1, 'transaction' => 2]];
$array2 = ['function_maps' => ['subid' => 4, 'purchase' => '40 EUR']];
$result = replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [function_maps] => Array
        (
            [subid] => 4
            [transaction] => 2
            [purchase] => 40 EUR
        )

)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/456067)

Comment: Or, you know, [`array_replace_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive), which will do what the OP wants given the provided input.

Answer (score 0):

People from IRC chat gave me the solution, which easily solves the case:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php